# The misconceived difference between the electrostatic and electric force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields

Some sources are saying that electrostatic (coulombic) and electric forces are the same concept in electrostatics (that is the force that an electric charge experiences in an electric field).

While other sources are saying they are different, that a electrostatic force, is used for when the charges are not moving relative to one another (which is impossible in less there is no net force), and electric force is used when charges are moving.

Would an expert in electricity please consult me the conceptual difference between electrostatic and electric forces?

Comment: The answer is that this is a really tiny choice of words which nobody really cares about... it is like asking if 3 bananas is enough to count as "a bunch of bananas", or whether a hot dog is a sandwich. Do you know what equations apply and what happens in a given situation? If you do, there's no problem.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for your comment. I am more interested in the conceptual difference between electrostatic and and electric forces. I only know coulombs law, which is for the electrostatic force experienced between two stationary charges right? But what force law models the electric force experience by a moving charge?

Comment: It's $\mathbf{F} = q (\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B})$ which is called the Lorentz force law. The two terms are called the electric and magnetic forces.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for your comment! You should post this is the answers :) So the electrostatic force is the force experienced between two stationary charges, which is mediated by the electrostatic field. And the electric force is the force experienced between two charges moving relative to each other, and is mediated by the electric field, right? Also is it possible for the electric force to be completely electrostatic because I thought absolute rest in our universe was impossible?! Many thanks, Callum

Answer (score 1):

(It's a good idea to provide specific references, rather than some vague "source".)

The electric force is $\vec F_{elec}=q\vec E$.

- Such a force can be called "electrostatic"
  the curl of the electric field is zero $\vec\nabla\times\vec E=\vec 0$,
  as is the case when the sources of the electric field are charges at rest.
  (A related characterization of electrostatics is $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s=0$ along any closed path.)
- When the curl is not zero, then by Faraday's Law, there is a changing magnetic field: $\vec\nabla\times\vec E=-\frac{d}{dt}\vec B$. (That is, there is a non-coulombic source of the electric field.) The electric force associated with this electric field would not be called electrostatic.

  (That there may be a magnetic force in this case is a different force. The electric force is still defined as above.)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So an electrostatic field is produced when charge are at rest, but is what defines a charge 'at rest'?

Comment: Also is it true that there is no such electrostatic force because all charges are moving relative to each other so experience an electric force

Comment: "At rest" is a perfectly defined notion, it's just frame-dependent (as is the electric field itself). Be careful, depending on the charges you're talking about, it might be Newtonian or relativistic mechanics territory.